# Docker server has unreachable subdomains

Tags: docker, go

I have a Golang server that already has working subdomains.
It works perfectly by itself and the subdomains are reachable.
I have now converted it into a docker image and the subdomains don't work at all.

so `localhost:8000` is reachable, but `api.localhost:8000`  doesn't work.

Here is my docker-compose

```
version: "3"

services:
      
  caddyserver:
    image: caddy:2.1.1-alpine
    container_name: caddyserver
    hostname: caddyserver
    env_file:
      - ./config.env
 
    ports:
      #- 443:443
      #- 80:80
      - 8080:8080

    volumes:
      - "./caddy_secrets/data_lets_encrypt_storage:/data"
      - "./caddy_secrets/config_storage:/config"
      - ./Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile


  zipperapiv2:
    image: elgonlabs/zipperapiv2:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    container_name: zipperapiv2
    hostname: zipperapiv2 
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - api.zipperapiv2
    extra_hosts:
      #- "api.zipperapiv2:127.0.0.1"
      #- "otherhost:50.31.209.229"
    volumes:
      - "/home/edwin/Projects/zipperapiv2_prod/config.env:/go/config.env"
      - "/home/edwin/Projects/zipperapiv2_prod/config.toml:/go/config.toml"
      - "/home/edwin/Projects/zipperapiv2_prod/logs:/go/logs"
      - "/home/edwin/Projects/zipperapiv2_prod/machinery-config.yml:/go/machinery-config.yml"
 
volumes:
  zipperapiv2:
```

At this point I am trying everything. How do I get the subdomains to work?

Comment: You need to add the hostname in order for your browser to understand which is the right hostname to resolve. If you're on a Mac od Linux PC, add `127.0.0.1        api.localhost` to `/etc/hosts` and it should work.

Comment: I don't understand. I am just running this container by itself. It actually fully works when I utilize host network(network_mode: "host")

Comment: Well, it involves DNS, networking etc. Unless you have a domain name registered for your local app, the browser cannot find it anywhere on the internet.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually doing it wrong. I was using the container name inside the container to create subdomains. I guess localhost inside the container works well.